# Creating revision Unable to create 0 instances for "Cloud Run" because there are already 0 in this region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have requested a cpu upgrade for region us-east1 to google cloud and was denied. Why was it denied? Currently I can't create a single instance of Google Cloud Run because I already hit the 8 CPU limit in the region us-east1. Although the latter is not clear to me because according to quotas I have used only 25% of the quota.

1. SQL: instance 4 cpu.
2. VPC Serverless: instance minimum 2 cpu && maximum 5 cpu
3. Google Cloud Run: 2 services each of 1 cpu. And I can't create more services in google cloud run.

Creating revision Unable to create 0 instances for "fruver-web-00005-nah" because there are already 0 in this region.

I can't delete any of them because I need all of them and they are necessary. what am i doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there's currently a bug :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278096734

No fix known at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

According to this  [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/understand_limits#about_increase_requests):

> Most quota increase requests are evaluated by automated systems. Their decision is based on strict criteria, including the availability of resources, the length of time you've used Google Cloud, and other factors. Requests that don't meet specific criteria are denied. Evaluation criteria for automated reviews is not disclosed to ensure fairness for all customers and prevent attempts to manipulate the process. Sometimes, quota increase requests are escalated to human reviewers, who also follow strict criteria but can consider your unique circumstances.

[To increase the quota](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#increase) you can follow this step:

> 1. Go to the Cloud Run Quotas page.
> 2. Select the quota(s) you want to modify for applicable regions and click EDIT        QUOTAS.
> 3. If prompted, provide your user information, and enter the new quota limit for each quota you  selected.

If you are still unable to upgrade, feel free to contact [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to get your quota increased.

Answer (score 1):

As someone is already described this is the latest issue occured in GCP. I was also facing the similar issue **( Unable to create 1 instances for because there are already 8 in this region. )** and **I found the hack by changing the region.** Hope this will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. You are reaching the region quota.

If you have more than 10 services in a region, you should split them.

For example, if you have 13 services in us-east1, delete half of them and change the region.

Do it like 7 services in us-east1 and 6 services in us-east4.

I had the same problem and solved it this way.